# OneDrive file access with php using microsoft graph

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I tried using [the library from krizalys](https://github.com/krizalys/onedrive-php-sdk) for an implementation to read and write files from OneDrive. It should work for business accounts but would be nice if it could also work for personal accounts.

Since I read that the Live SDK used in krizalys example will be offline soon ([as mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/migrating-from-live-sdk)), I tried implementing Microsoft Graph instead.

I implemented two ways to get an access token at the moment, one with grant type `password` ([getAccessToken Method from this sample used](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/php-connect-rest-sample/blob/master/tests/IntegrationTest.php)) and one with `client_credentials` (Like in the [krizalys lib](https://github.com/krizalys/onedrive-php-sdk)). Both seem to work and return an `access_token` and `refresh_token`, but when I try to make a request I get the message:

> "InvalidAuthenticationToken [message] => Access token is empty"

The code for my request:

```
$data = array("name" => "test");
$url  = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root";
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
  'headers' => [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->_state->token->data->access_token,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' .strlen(json_encode($data))
   ],
   'body' => json_encode($data),
]);
```

I also tried it with the GET method and added the `Host: graph.microsoft.com` to ensure that this is not the problem:

```
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
  'headers' => [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->_state->token->data->access_token,
    'Host: graph.microsoft.com'
  ],
]);
```

The token response payload looks like this:
[image]

The application is configured at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and the permissions are set. Is there anything wrong with my request? I have no idea why I always get the `InvalidAuthenticationToken` message. Thanks.

Comment: can you check `$this->_state->token->data->access_token` that is not empty or so ?

Comment: What scopes are you requesting? It would be helpful if you included an example `access_token` that you received.

Comment: @Edwin: the token is not null or empty, i stepped through the code and checked if it is set at the needed position.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur: When i request with grant_type "password" i just set https://graph.microsoft.com as resource and get the scopes as configured in my apps.dev.microsoft.com. (I also tried adding scopes but that didnt change anything). When using grant_type "client_credentials" i used "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" as scope.
I added the requested access token data to my question.

Comment: so here (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user) you have another header parameter  `host`, I don't know if that will change something, but worth trying it

Comment: @Edwin: nice idea, thanks, but unfortunately it didn't work either. I added the code with the `Host` parameter to the question, maybe it will help somehow.

Comment: That is the return payload, the token itself is in the `access_token` property. A screenshot isn't sufficient, it is truncating the token (and no one is going to hand-enter the token to decode it).

Comment: @MarcLaFleur: ok, thank you for the information. I added the token value to the question too.

Comment: you can decode very easily here https://jwt.io/ so I wouldn't share the `access_token` if I don't want to share the info in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've registered your application in the v2 Endpoint (`apps.dev.microsoft.com`) but the sample code you're using is for the v1 Endpoint. These are not interchangeable. Also, `password` isn't a valid OAuth Grant for the v2 Endpoint (v2 supports `authorization_code`, `implicit`, and `client_credentials`)

You need to obtain your token from the v2 Endpoint. You might find these articles helpful:

- [Microsoft v2 Endpoint Primer](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/).
- [Azure AD v2.0 Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview)

Comment: I got that `password` isn't a valid OAuth Grant and switched to my other implementation using `client_credentials` and still get my token this way. I read those articles but i still feel dumb not getting this to work. I don't get how i would register my application for v1 Endpoint or what code to use to access v2 Endpoint.

Comment: I just recognized that when i switch to `client_credentials` type and change use `curl` for requests i get the message `CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217`, but i can't find any help to fix that one.

Comment: It seems i got what you wanted to tell me now. Using the v2 Endpoint with the Lib `https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/tree/dev/src` works with the obtained token. Would still be interesting, how i can obtain the token for the v1 Endpoint and talk to that one because i couldnt figure that out.